# Bind ComboBox to Two Lists in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have two lists. The first one is hard-coded and the contents never change. The second can be edited by the user to add, change and remove items:

```
public List<Item> DefaultItems = new List<Item>();
public BindingList<Item> UserItems = new BindingList<Item>();
...
MyTable.DataSource = UserItems;
```

I would like to bind the contents of both lists, one after the other, to a ComboBox and have it update automatically when the user edits the UserItems list.

The first part I can easily solve with something like:

```
public List<Items> AllItems
{
    get
    {
        List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
        foreach (Item I in DefaultItems) Items.Add(I);
        foreach (Item I in UserItems) Items.Add(I);
        return Items;
    }
}
...
MyComboBox.DataSource = AllItems;
```

The problem is that when UserItems changes there is no notification that AllItems has changed so the contents of the combobox remain the same.

I then added an event that is generated when UserItems changes. Now my problem is how to force the ComboBox to refresh. Doing the following:

```
MyComboBox.DataSource = null;
MyComboBox.DataSource = AllItems;
```

results in the selecteditem becoming null and the selectedindex becoming -1, which I then have to handle in my code (temporarily remember the current item, restore it afterwards, etc.). It's all becoming very messy and I'm sure there is a clever way of solving this. Is there?

thanks, Andy

UPDATE: I didn't want to add yet more code and complexity just for this in the form of a third party assembly, so I just continued with my messy approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a collection that will notify the UI when the collection has been changed.

You can either use the .NET provided [`BindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) class or, if you want to try something different, you could download the [`BindingListView`](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) class that will wrap your existing collections and provide the UI with the notification it needs.

Comment: I changed the AllItems list to a BindingList and it didn't make any difference. I think this is because the add/change/remove operation is not occurring on that list but on a different list.

Comment: @Andy - That would be correct. The changes have to be made to the BindingList. That's why I suggested taking a look at the BindingListView as well.

Comment: Why doesn't AllItems.ResetBindings(); work here? It should raise the listchanged event and cause the combobox to refresh, but it doesn't. Seems the perfect solution.